# how to color logs text in Loki Grafana

Tags: logging, format, grafana, grafana-loki

I use `winston` to format my nodejs logs as `format.json` and send them to Loki Grafana.

There they are correctly interpreted as jsons, and Grafana auto-detects their level and puts a nice colored bar to their left (red for `error`, green for `info`, etc)

However, Id like to see the whole log text in that color. Now they are all in white.

Anyone knows how to give them color?

(I tried using format.combine(colorize, json) in winston: Grafana then shows the colors but fails to parse the json, so that doesn't work)